# Pandas: get rid of timestamp in specific multiindex level

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have the following df:

```
                                   Count
(2020-01-01,          ABC1)        1
(2019-04-11 00:00:00, ABC2)        3
(2020-04-15 00:00:00, ABC3)        5
(2019-10-29,          ABC4)        7
(2019-08-10,          ABC5)        9
```

I noticed that my index is messed up, so how can I get rid of the timestamp, leaving only the date?

Desired outcome:

```
              Name                 Count
2020-01-01    ABC1                 1
2019-04-11    ABC2                 3
2020-04-15    ABC3                 5
2019-10-24    ABC4                 7
2019-08-10    ABC5                 9
```

Comment: It's hard to reconstruct your data. Can you do `print(df.to_dict())`?

Comment: you can use pd.read_clipboard()

Comment: Are the items in your index `tuples`?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma yep

Comment: Actually yes one can use `read_clipboard`, but this will not give the exact structure of your dataframe or more exactly index, and your question is specific on how to deal with this structure to get the expected result :) hence @Quang Hoang question

Comment: @Zizzipupp I guess there is a typo in your expected output, at  `2019-10-24`?